# How do STL containers copy objects?

Tags: c++, stl, constructor

I know STL containers like `vector` copies the object when it is added. `push_back` method looks like:

```
void push_back ( const T& x );
```

I am surprised to see that it takes the item as *reference*. I wrote a sample program to see how it works.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Inside Foo constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo& f)
    {
        std::cout << "inside copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo f;
std::vector<Foo> foos;
foos.push_back(f);
```

This copies the object and I can see it is calling *copy-constructor*.

My question is, when the `push_back` takes item as reference, how it is calling copy-constructor? Or am I missing something here?

Any thoughts..?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It probably uses "placement `new`" to construct the object in-place in its internal array. Placement `new` doesn't allocate any memory; it just places the object where you specify, and calls the constructor. The syntax is `new (address) Class(constructor_arguments)`.

The copy constructor `T::T(T const &)` is called to create the copy in-place. Something like this (simplified):

```
template<T>
void vector<T>::push_back(T const &item) {
    // resize if necessary
    new (&d_array[d_size++]) T(item);
}
```

Note that `T` must have a copy constructor for this to work. By default (if you do nothing), it gets one for free. If you define it explicitly, it must be `public` for `vector<T>` to work.

[Here's how GNU's libstdc++ does it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01011_source.html#l00721), but I doubt that it'll be very enlightening. There is an allocator (the second template argument to `vector`) that makes it less straightforward.

Comment: This is OK when T has got a parameterless constructor. But what will happen when it has a parameterized constructor? How vector can initialize new object?

Comment: This is OK when T has got a _copy constructor_. Which is does, by default, and if you implement it, unless you explicitly made it `private` or `protected`.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate further.

Comment: Your explanation is clear. I am wondering, why they don't have a  signature like `push_back(T const item)` and by avoiding the placement new.

Comment: This would make a copy of the item when it is passed into the function (because it's pass-by-value), which the pass-by-reference version avoids. It could avoid placement `new` by using the `=` operator, but that would require that there is already an initialized object in that place (to call `operator=` on) and thus require `T` to have a default constructor.

Comment: The other advantage of using placement new is that the unused space which the vector has allocated, but which has not yet been filled, doesn't have to be initialised at all. This is a small optimisation if the default constructor of T exists and doesn't do much, but a significant difference if the default constructor of T does a lot of work, or has side-effects. And as Thomas points out, it allows T to have no no-args constructor at all.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ SDK always takes `const T &` as function parameter for efficiency.

In your case if it take `T` as parameter, the copy action will be done twice, one for passing it to function `push_back(f)`, one for internal adding it to the container. And by taking `const T&` as parameter only one copy is needed!

Answer (score 1):

It uses the placement new operator and copy-constructs it to unitialized memory;

The placement new creates a new element at a specified adress in memory, in the vector case, the current end();

```
void push_back(const T& val){
::new (&*end()) T(val);
[increase end]
}
```

look at http://spotep.com/dev/devector.h which has quite clear code (as opposed to most STL implementations).