# About passing variables to STL containers and not losing them out of scope

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, scope

Say we have the following code:

```
void foo()
{
        Point newpoint(...);
        dq.push_back(newpoint);
        ...
        return dq;
}
```

Suppose `dq` is deque, `Point` is some class.

in `C`, when `foo()` ends, then `newpoint` is gone and if it was passed to an array for example, it would've become garbage, but I see that in `c++`, `dq` actually keeps it when it's out of `foo()`'s scope, did it actually invoke a copy constructor on `newpoint`? What really happens to `newpoint`? and is this a feature of STL containers or `C++`'s constructors?

Comment: Yes the STL containers will perform a copy usually in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693042/how-do-stl-containers-copy-objects

Comment: The bigger question is how you manage to return a `deque` from `void foo()` :)

Comment: @Praetorian lol, oops.

Comment: `newpoint` is gone, but that doesn't matter because `newpoint` isn't stored in the deque, only another Point that happens to have the same values. It's also the same in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> did it actually invoke a copy constructor on `newpoint`?

Yes.

> and is this a feature of STL containers or C++'s constructors?

A STL container with element type `T` always contains `T` objects, rather than pointer-to-`T` or reference-to-`T`. When initializing an object of type `T` from an expression of type `T`, a copy or move is performed.

If you used `deque<reference_wraper<Point>>` instead then the deque would contain references to `Point` rather than `Point` objects, and no copies of `Point` would occur. It is good that you already understand how this would cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) will either copy the element or move the element into the container. This original `Point` goes out of scope at the end of the function but the container isn't storing a reference to this temporary so it's fine.